# Zend Framework first time setting it up from the begining

Tags: php, zend-framework

Ok, not sure if this question fits here on SO or not. But Ill ask anyway. I know Zend is a MVC, and with that almost all MVC's Zend or otherwise that I have worked with or installed all come with a load of files and the core directory structure you'd expect. Example the company I work for currently uses Zend, and them like all other companies I have worked for that use Zend as well all share a similar Folder Structure:

```
IE:
  application
  config
  controllers
  data
  library
  model
  views
  webroot
```

However going to the Zend site, downloading the ZF2 package I unpack it I see only a couple examples of stuff built within Zend. But nothing pertaining to a structure like that, then I find out I have to do some Skeleton build or whatever, and I try that, and still see nothing similar. So with that my question is, am I doing something wrong? Or am I grabbing the wrong stuff from there site? Ideas?

Comment: I have no answer to your question but a suggestion which might help. If you play with ZF2 use "composer" to install it (instead of downloading and unpacking it). If I remember right there is a quickstart in the manual. It will encourage you to use composer and it will come with a skeleton.

Comment: I followed that, and I have it installed and all else with composer. I guess I was thrown off by the end result, as someone pointed out in other answers the structures are different from ZF1 and ZF2, never having set ZF up from the ground up, and just diving in and working with it like I have over the years I think my confusion comes from there. So Im just gonna have to take baby steps to get it implemented/installed correctly, so I can remember for the next time. And go from there. When its come to rolling out a new mvc I've always ended up with CI or similar, which is just unpack, go

Answer (score 2):

The directory structure of ZF2 is different from that of ZF1. The major difference is that a ZF2 application is organised in modules. Each module basically has its own directories for the models, views and controllers.

The quickest way to get the "correct" file structure probably is to start building your app on top of the [ZendSkeletonApplication](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication). Also looking at other modules (for example at the [ZF2 modules directory](http://modules.zendframework.com/)) might help to understand the directory structure of ZF2 better. As an example consider the [ZfcUser](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser) module: It contains a simple user authentication module with [a controller](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/tree/master/src/ZfcUser/Controller), the [data model](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/tree/master/src/ZfcUser) and the [views](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/tree/master/view).

Answer (score 0):

The file structure you've given is roughly the standard file structure for a ZF **1** app. If you check the ZF1 manual you'll see the same file structure there: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/project-structure.project.html. ZF2 (the current version) works a bit differently.

Comment: That could be it, I don't know what versions of Zend I have worked with in the past, but over the years its grown on me, and I want to develop my own stuff on it. So thank you for pointing that out its possible I have been using a earlier version and still being new from the level of ground up with zend, I just didnt know better.

Comment: @chris "in the past" "over the years" it must of been ZF1. ZF2 just came out.